# Css animation transition using @keyframe not working

Tags: html, css

I am working on css animation transition.I have **div id mybus**. It's position is **relative**. It is the container of **multiple divs position relative**. I am trying to move the mybus which is the container of all other divs using animation transform: translateX(). It's not woking. (Question is, does position matter while animation?)
I separately applied animation which is transform: rotate() to the div class wheels (It is also inside mybus)which is working well. (I did't include this part of code ) I can give more info about code if needed.

```css
.mybus{
  position: relative; 
  animation-name:busgo;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /* animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

@keyframes busgo{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(-1220px);
  }   
}

.busBody{
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
}

#front{
    height:60px;
    width:70px;
    top:130px;
    left:200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

#back{
    height:90px;
    width:200px;
    top:100px;
    left:270px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.window{
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
    background-color: dimgray;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#w1{
    top:110px;
    left:300px;
}

#w2{
    top:110px;
    left:360px;
}

#w3{
    top:110px;
    left:420px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mybus">
  <div class="busBody" id="front"></div>
  <div class="busBody" id="back"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w1"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w2"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w3"></div>
  <div class="wheel" id="wh1"></div>
  <div class="wheel" id="wh2"></div>
  <div class="headlight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try #mybus, your using id not class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using `.mybus` instead of `#mybus`

```css
#mybus{
  position: relative; 
  animation-name:busgo;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /* animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

@keyframes busgo{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(-1220px);
  }   
}

.busBody{
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
}

#front{
    height:60px;
    width:70px;
    top:130px;
    left:200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

#back{
    height:90px;
    width:200px;
    top:100px;
    left:270px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.window{
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
    background-color: dimgray;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#w1{
    top:110px;
    left:300px;
}

#w2{
    top:110px;
    left:360px;
}

#w3{
    top:110px;
    left:420px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mybus">
  <div class="busBody" id="front"></div>
  <div class="busBody" id="back"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w1"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w2"></div>
  <div class="window" id="w3"></div>
  <div class="wheel" id="wh1"></div>
  <div class="wheel" id="wh2"></div>
  <div class="headlight"></div>
</div>
```